# BlackBerry HorizontalFieldManager alignment

Tags: blackberry

Horizontally, I want to display two bitmaps, and between them display a label field. 
The code seems straightforward, but all the fields are added on the left side of the screen.

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();

callbmp = new BitmapField(ei.getBitmap(),Field.FOCUSABLE |BitmapField.FIELD_LEFT);
LabelField NAME = new LabelField("mylable", LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER);
mailbmp = new BitmapField(mail.getBitmap(),Field.FOCUSABLE|BitmapField.FIELD_RIGHT);
hfm.add(callbmp);
hfm.add(NAME);
hfm.add(mailbmp);
add(hfm);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HorizontalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/HorizontalFieldManager.html) lays out the fields left-to-right in the order in which they are added.  The style bits for horizontal layout are ignored.

If you want left, right and center on a horizontal line, you'll need a custom manager.

Comment: thank u  very much.. can u pls post some code how can i arrange left,right and center in custom manager

Comment: That would be a significant investment in my time and would only hurt you - you need to learn how to do this on your own.   RIM had a talk at the last devcon about advanced layout, that included a manager that does this, but I'm not able to find it right now.

Answer (score 6):

```
 Manager customManager = new Manager(0)
 {
     protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
         setPositionChild(
             getField(0), 
             0, 
             0);
         layoutChild(
             getField(0), 
             getField(0).getPreferredWidth(), 
             getField(0).getPreferredHeight());

         setPositionChild(
             getField(1), 
             Graphics.getScreenWidth()/2 - getField(1).getPreferredWidth()/2, 
             0);
         layoutChild(
             getField(1), 
             getField(1).getPreferredWidth(), 
             getField(1).getPreferredHeight());    

         setPositionChild(
             getField(2), 
             Graphics.getScreenWidth() - getField(2).getPreferredWidth(), 
             0);
         layoutChild(
             getField(2), 
             getField(2).getPreferredWidth(), 
             getField(2).getPreferredHeight());    

         setExtent(width, height);
     }      
 };

 customManager.add(new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image1.png")));
 customManager.add(new LabelField("Hello Alignment"));
 customManager.add(new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image2.png")));
```

Answer (score 2):

**This should be your requirement:**
[image]

It can be done simply by subtracting the widths of the items you are adding on your horizontal field manager. By default the `leftButton` or the first item you add on the HFM will be added on left. Then you can add your label(`userName`) and the `rightButton` in the following way:

```
LabelField userName = new LabelField("MaheshBabu");
HorizontalFieldManager horizontalBar = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH|Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
horizontalBar.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLACK));

rightButton.setMargin(0, 0, 0, Display.getWidth()-rightButton.getPreferredWidth()-leftButton.getPreferredWidth()-userName.getPreferredWidth());

horizontalBar.add(leftButton);
horizontalBar.add(userName);
horizontalBar.add(rightButton);
```