# Disappearing buttons in BlackBerry HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I ma new to BB development. I have a field manager defined and set like:

```
horizontalField= new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
setStatus(horizontalField);
```

I have a button and a checkbox

```
CheckboxField chkBuffer=new CheckboxField("Buffer" ,true);

ButtonField sendButton=new ButtonField("Send")
```

When I try to add these to the horizontal FM, only check box appears and the button is not visible for some reason. I add them like

```
 horizontalField.add(chkBuffer);

 horizontalField.add(sendButton);
```

Any ideas about what can be going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

```
  final CheckboxField chk=new CheckboxField(){
        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            super.layout(25, 20);
        }
    };
```

Comment: I get an error for the layout method saying : Cannot override the final method from Manager

Comment: This works but it displays it very poorly. I don't even get to see the text. I tried to change the width but nothing happened. Any ways to make it look better ?

Comment: change 25 to a bigger value. (say 100), then it will display the full text.

Answer (score 1):

**This will also help you and is easy too:**

```
horizontalField.add(chkBuffer);

sendButton.setMargin(0, 0, 0, Display.getWidth()-chkBuffer.getPreferredWidth()-sendButton.getPreferredWidth());

horizontalField.add(sendButton);
```

Take a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183026/blackberry-horizontalfieldmanager-alignment/12910943#12910943)** also.