# HorizontalFieldManager alignment in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Horizontally, I want to display two custom buttons, and between them display a label field in a BlackBerry app. I looked at "[BlackBerry HorizontalFieldManager alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183026/blackberry-horizontalfieldmanager-alignment)", but did not achieve any success.
Here is a screenshot that I want to create in BlackBerry.
[image]

**Here is the code that I created for this screen:**

```
 package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.XYEdges; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BasicEditField; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.PasswordEditField; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Background; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BackgroundFactory; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Border; 
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BorderFactory;

  /**
 * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard * behavior   for BlackBerry GUI applications. */ public final class HelloBlackBerryScreen extends MainScreen { BasicEditField username; PasswordEditField password;

 /**
* Creates a new MyScreen object
*/ public HelloBlackBerryScreen() {   // Set the linear background.  this.getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(0x91e7ff,0x0099CCFF,0x00336699,0x91e7ff));
 // SET HEADER OF SCREEN VerticalFieldManager vfm = new
 VerticalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH); BitmapField header = new
 BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("header.png"),FIELD_HCENTER);

 HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new
 HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_VCENTER |Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
setTitle(header);

hfm.add(vfm); add(hfm);  

//SET Container 

 LabelField usernameTxt = new LabelField("Username:",LabelField.FIELD_TOP);

 usernameTxt.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 30));

 usernameTxt.setMargin(20, 0, 0, 160);

 LabelField passwordTxt = new LabelField("Password :",LabelField.FIELD_BOTTOM);

  passwordTxt.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 30));

  passwordTxt.setMargin(10, 0, 0, 160);

   username = new BasicEditField(BasicEditField.FIELD_BOTTOM);username.setMargin(10, 110, 0, 160);   //username.setMaxSize(getHeight());  
   username.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(3, 3,3, 3), 0x999999, Border.STYLE_FILLED));
   username.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0xe0e0e0));
     password = new PasswordEditField();   password.setMargin(10, 110, 0,160);  password.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new
       XYEdges(3, 3, 3, 3), 0x999999, Border.STYLE_FILLED));
     password.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0xe0e0e0));

  ButtonField loginBtn = new ButtonField("   Log-In   ", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);   loginBtn.setMargin(30, 0, 0,240);
  ButtonField recoveryBtn = new ButtonField("Forget Password", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);   recoveryBtn.setMargin(10, 0, 0,200);


  add(usernameTxt); add(username); add(passwordTxt); add(password);
  add(loginBtn); add(recoveryBtn);
  loginBtn.setChangeListener(btnlistener); } FieldChangeListener
  btnlistener = new FieldChangeListener() {

      public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {  
          //Open a new screen   
           String uname = username.getText();   
           String pwd   =password.getText();

        //If there is no input  if (uname.length() == 0 || pwd.length()==0)
          Dialog.alert("One of the textfield is empty!");       
          else if
          (uname.equals("user") && pwd.equals("admin"))
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(newwelcome());         
            //Open a
            new Screen else 
               Dialog.alert("Username or password not found!");     
             }

       };

         FieldChangeListener btnlistener2 = new FieldChangeListener() {

       public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {     
           screen if variables are not empty




            [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlDRu.png
```

Comment: Please format your code in the question editor using the **{ }** button.  You also need to paste it in from an editor (IDE) that puts spaces in for indentation, not tabs.  This code is unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to use custom manager like this.

**Main Field Manager for this screen**

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT
                |VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH|VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_VCENTER|VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER){
            //Override the paint method to draw the background image.
            public void paint(Graphics graphics){
                //Draw the background image and then call super.paint
                //to paint the rest of the screen.
                    graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE);
                graphics.clear();
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
        };

        add(vfm);
```

and add custom manger like this

//Placing back,home icon and title at particular positions

```
HorizontalFieldManager customManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager
                .USE_ALL_WIDTH)
        {
            //Applying background color for that Manager
            public void paint(Graphics graphics)
            {
                graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE);//blue
                graphics.clear();
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
            //Placing the Fields
            protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {

                setPositionChild(
                        getField(0), 
                        0, 
                        0);
                layoutChild(
                        getField(0), 
                        getField(0).getPreferredWidth(), 
                        getField(0).getPreferredHeight());

                setPositionChild(
                        getField(1), 
                        Display.getWidth()/2 - getField(1).getPreferredWidth()/2, 
                        0);
                layoutChild(
                        getField(1), 
                        getField(1).getPreferredWidth(), 
                        getField(1).getPreferredHeight());    

                setPositionChild(
                        getField(2), 
                        Display.getWidth() - getField(2).getPreferredWidth(), 
                        0);
                layoutChild(
                        getField(2), 
                        getField(2).getPreferredWidth(), 
                        getField(2).getPreferredHeight());    

                setExtent(width, 50);
            }      
        };
```

//To display Back icon

```
 final Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("back.png");
  BitmapField bmpfield1 = new BitmapField(bmp1,BitmapField.FOCUSABLE|BitmapField.FIELD_LEFT);
```

//To display Home icon

```
final Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("home.png");
BitmapField bmpfield2 = new BitmapField(bmp2,BitmapField.FOCUSABLE |BitmapField.FIELD_RIGHT);
```

//To display Title

```
LabelField lbl = new LabelField("Login",LabelField.FIELD_VCENTER);
```

//To Add Fields

```
customManager.add(bmpfield1);
customManager.add(lbl);
customManager.add(bmpfield2);
vfm. add(customManager);
```

Comment: the problem i am facing now is i want to make this "header " fix for the screen.like it should remain fix on the top of the screen.how to achieve this task? kindly help me "user 1213202" and thanks for your response

Comment: this will be fixed only.i did n't get exactly what u r asking.if u want any other fields after that custom manager you can add it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix your header at the top as I understood from your comments what you can do is create a `HorizontalFieldManager` and add your back, title and home button to it then you can set that horizontal field manager in your title using [setTitle(hfm)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html#setTitle%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field%29). Similarly if you also need to fix your footer you may use `setStatus(hfm)`.